# $\left< \frac{\partial (xp)}{\partial t} \right> = 0$ When is this true?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises

Is this always true in quantum mechanics?

$$\left< \frac{\partial (xp)}{\partial t} \right> = 0$$

I encountered this when working problem 3.31 in Griffiths Introduction to Quantum Mechanics II.

He does this in his solutions manual:
$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left<Q\right> = \frac{i}{\hbar}\left<[\hat{H}, \hat{Q}]\right> + \left< \frac{\partial \hat{Q}}{\partial t} \right> $$

$$ \frac{d}{dt}\left<xp\right> = \frac{i}{\hbar}\left<[H, xp]\right> $$

I'm not sure why $\left< \frac{\partial (xp)}{\partial t} \right> = 0$. It sort of seems plausible that the expectation of a change in $xp$ with respect to time would be $0$ due to symmetry but is there more to it?

Comment: $\frac{ \partial {\hat Q} }{ \partial t}$ means that one should take a derivative of the operator ${\hat Q}$ keeping $x$ and $p$ fixed, i.e. it keeps track of explicit time dependences that operators map have. The operator $xp$ has no explicit time dependence. Hence $\frac{ \partial (xp) }{ \partial t} = 0$.

Comment: +! for getting the equation to work in the header!